# Terraform CLI Login with token throwing error

Tags: terraform

Following the tutorial for logging into the Terraform CLI [here](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/cloud-login?in=terraform/cloud) and am getting the below error each time I run the `terraform login` command and paste the generated API key into my terminal:

```
Error: Token is invalid: unauthorized
```

What am I missing here?  I haven't seen a clear guide anywhere that shows the resolution for this sort of error, so figured it would be helpful to the community to have one on here.  Terraform version is 1.0.0.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Most likely explanation is a copy/paste or character formatting issue. Can you verify the correct token with correct formatting is input?

Comment: @MattSchuchard - I've used multiple ways to copy the key and paste it into my terminal: highlight and clicking the built-in 'copy to clipboard' button both result in the same error.

Comment: I have the same problem, cannot paste even though the token is on the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a couple different ways to reproduce and haven't been able to do so. Outside of something potentially silly, like restarting your terminal session, you might opt for using a .terraformrc (assuming Linux/MacOS, terraform.rc on Windows) file to assign the credentials through `credentials` block.

Details on setting up a Terraform config file are: [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/config/config-file.html#credentials)

Answer (score 0):

Received same error on Windows 10.  May be a utf8/ANSI issue.  Quick work-around:
a) Copy token from browser.
b) Open notepad, paste the copied token and save file as ANSI encoded.
c) Then copy the ANSI version of the token.